# Find x that fulfills these conditions?

Tags: geometry

Given two vectors: u = (1 , -1)  &  v = (4 , x)
What is the value of x where the angle is pi/4?

Is it correct if i do this?:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YBAa.jpg)

Comment: Why the close votes? Is it because the question is not in MathJax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your work is correct, but you have a small sign error:

$$\cos(\pi/4) = \frac{4-x}{\sqrt2 \cdot \sqrt{16 \color{red}{+} x^2}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{4-x}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{16+x^2}}$$
$$\sqrt{16+x^2} = 4-x$$

Obviously $x=0$ is a solution. This can be proved as the only solution by returning back to the original probably and looking at it geometrically.

I would however like to use an alternative approach. Rotating $(1, -1)$ counter-clockwise around the $x$-axis by $45º$, the rotated point lies on the $x$-axis. We can do the same to $(4, x)$ using the rotation matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos 45º & -\sin 45º \\ \sin 45º & \cos 45º \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ x \end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} & \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ x \end{bmatrix}$$

$$= \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{x}{\sqrt2} +2\sqrt2 \\ \frac{x}{\sqrt2} +2\sqrt2  \end{bmatrix}$$

and to make the angle between the two vectors $45º$, $ -\frac{x}{\sqrt2} +2\sqrt2$ needs to be equal to $\frac{x}{\sqrt2} +2\sqrt2$. Can you continue?

Comment: No Toby, Im struggling to isolate x :(

Comment: It sounded like you were trying to verify your work, so please make this clearer next time.

Comment: In addition, are you sure the question is as stated? I think it is impossible for the angle between the two vectors to be $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: Sure, whatever works haha

Comment: Yes, that is the question. Maybe my teacher made a mistake?

Comment: There is definitely a mistake then. Maybe your teacher meant the angle is $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$?

Comment: Most probably. The homework he gave us had a lot of typos in it. So assuming the angle is 3pi/4, how would you solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98416/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-p97).

Comment: The angle between $(1,-1)$ and the positive $x$-axis is $\pi/4$, so it’s quite possible for $(4,x)$ to make this angle with it, too.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Solve the equation $$\frac{4-x}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{16+x^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$ for $x$

Comment: The RHS should be $\frac{4}{\sqrt2}$, right?